# Is InAppBrowser IPv6 enabled?

Tags: cordova, ipv6, inappbrowser

I searched on several foruns and I didn't find any specific information if InAppBrowser has IPv6 enable or not.

When I use: refWeb = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes', 'clearcache=yes', 'clearsessioncache=yes');

with url = http://192.168.1.210, it's working normally but if url = http://[2001::123:1:2:3] it shows a web page with error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

If I use a native browser (like Chrome) on same device, those url are working as expected.

Please help.